# Intriguing polynomials coming from a combinatorial physics problem

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, special-functions, q-analogs

For real $0<q<1$, integer $n >0 $ and integer $k\ge 0$, define 
$$[k, n]_q \equiv  -\sum_{m=1}^{n} q^{m(k+1)} (q^{-n}; q)_m =  -\sum_{m=1}^{n} q^{m(k+1)} \prod_{l=0}^{m-1} (1-q^{l-n})$$

where $(\cdot\; ; q)_n$ is a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.2.i).

These functions express exact occupation numbers of $k$-th energy level
in an ideal Fermi  gas with equidistant spectrum and exactly $n$ fermions.
(For physicists, $q$ is just $e^{-\Delta \epsilon/ kT}$).

My numerical experiments with *Mathematica* show so far :

1. All $[k, n]_q$ are polynomials in $q$.
2. $0<[k, n]_q<1$ for $0<q<1$.
3. $\lim\limits_{q\to 1} [k, n]_q = 0$.
4. $\lim\limits_{q\to 0} [k, n]_q = \begin{cases} 1,  & k < n \\ 0, &  k \ge n \end{cases}$.

Points (2.) to (4.) can be proven from the physics starting point, but I'm totally puzzled by (1.). The product from $l=0$ to $m-1$ contains  negative powers of $q$ because of  $n >l$, nevertheless, they conspire to cancel in the final sum.

**Why are these functions polynomials?** What would be the optimal way to compute their coefficients? Are there deeper mathematical properties to them?

**Combinatorial context**.
The original "combinatorial physics" definition of these numbers can be written as

$$[k, n]_q =\frac{\sum_{ \{ \nu_k \} } \nu_k q^{\sum_k k \nu_k} \delta_{n, \sum_k \nu_k}}{\sum_{ \{ \nu_k \} }q^{\sum_k k \nu_k} \delta_{n, \sum_k \nu_k}}$$

where the summation indices run as $\nu_k=0,1$ for $k=0, 1, 2 \ldots$. Properties (2.)-(4.) follow easily from this definition.
More physics context for the problem is being prepared for publication, see also a related post at [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27600/canonical-averages-in-a-fermi-gas-aka-generalized-fermi-dirac-distribution).

**Update**: A physics paper describing these polynomials has been [posted to arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6264), includes a reference to this question.

Comment: It might be helpful if you use the expression $$\sum_{m=1}^n \prod_{\ell=0}^{m-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell-n+1}\right)$$; for $n \leq k+1$, it's clear why they're polynomials. Why they're still polynomials when $n > k+1$ does not look so straightforward...

Comment: ...and since you're in *Mathematica* anyway: `QHypergeometricPFQ[{q^(-n), q}, {0}, q, q^(k + 1)] - 1` looks to be a more compact way of expressing your polynomials.

Comment: @J.M. useful indeed, thanks! (you've flipped the overall minus sign)

Comment: Taking the limit of $n \to \infty$, $|n-k|$=finite would also be very useful. If $q \to 1$ on top of it, this must give the Fermi function.

Comment: Or you could rewrite the product as $q^{-nm}\prod(q^n-q^l)$ and expand it into $q^{-nm}$ times a polynomial in $q$ whose coefficients are alternating sums of special partition functions...

Comment: @anon: would be very grateful if you elaborate a bit (perhaps submit an answer?): what are "special partition functions"? I'm asking since they seem to be closely related to physical canonical partition functions where this beast comes from...

Comment: Wait, doesn't point 4 imply that every negative power of $q$ in the function's expansion has coefficient zero? Though asking for a combinatorial or generatingfunctionological approach is intriguing.

Comment: @anon: ineed, you've solved the primary question! Point (4.) comes from the ground state with first $n$ levels occupied having the dominating Gibbs weight in $T\to 0$ limit. But indeed, the coefficients of these polynomials seems to be intriguingly small and non-trivial...

Comment: What I was thinking of was $$\prod_{l=0}^{m-1}(q^n-q^l)= \sum_{a=m(m-1)/2}^{n(m-1)} \left(\sum_{b=0}^{m-1} (-1)^b p_b(a-bn,m)\right)q^a,$$ where $p_e(f,g)$ counts the number of ways to write $f$ as a sum of $e$ numbers $\le g$. This gets very very complicated, obviously.

Comment: I have a suspicion that your polynomial is a special case of one of the $q$-Hahn class of orthogonal polynomials; I haven't fully browsed [the usual database](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/askey.html), but methinks it's in there somewhere...

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard the phrase «combinatorial physics» :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: it is also known as "statistical physics before thermodynamic limit" :) I've added a link from "combinatorial" to "physics" at the end of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some digging through Koekoek and Swarttouw's [*The Askey-scheme of hypergeometric orthogonal polynomials and its $q$-analogue*](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/as98.pdf) reveals that $[k,n]_q$ is related to the [Al-Salam-Carlitz](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/mana.19650300105) I polynomials (see page 115 of Koekoek and Swarttouw). More precisely,

$$1-[k,n]_q={}_2\phi_1\left({{q^{-n},q}\atop{0}}; q, q^{k+1}\right)=(-1)^n q^{\frac{n}2(2k-n+3)}U_n^{(q^{-k-1})}\left(\frac1{q};q\right)$$

In particular, letting $S(n,k;q)=1-[k,n]_q$, there is the three-term recurrence

$$S(n+1,k;q)=(1+q^{k+1}-q^{k-n})S(n,k;q)-q^{k+1}(1-q^{-n})S(n-1,k;q)$$

with the initial conditions $S(0,k;q)=1,\quad S(1,k;q)=q^{k+1}-q^k+1$.

From the relation with the Al-Salam-Carlitz II polynomials (see page 116 of Koekoek and Swarttouw), we have another basic hypergeometric expression:

$$1-[k,n]_q={}_2\phi_0\left({{q^n,\frac1{q}}\atop{-}}; \frac1{q}, q^{k-n+1}\right)$$

(*Mathematica* note: unfortunately *Mathematica* doesn't have support for ${}_2\phi_0$... yet.)

One can also derive a "reversal" identity by reversing the summation order:

$$\begin{align*}1-[k,n]_q&=q^{n(k+1)}(q^{-n};q)_n\; {}_1 \phi_1\left({{q^{-n}}\atop{q^{-n}}};q,q^{-k}\right)\\&=(-1)^n q^{\frac{n}{2}(2k-n+1)}(q;q)_n\; {}_1 \phi_1\left({{q^{-n}}\atop{q^{-n}}};q,q^{-k}\right)\end{align*}$$

I'll update this post if I manage to dig up more information...

Comment: Confirm you three-term recurrence wtih small exmaples. It is also consistent with @PeterTaylor result.

Comment: I have a problem with your last equation: using [the definition](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.4.i) of ${}_2\phi_0$ and a $q$-Pochhammer [identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.2.E6) I recover the original definition in terms of $(q^{-n} ; q)_m$ but with an extra factor of $(q^{-1} ; q^{-1})_m$ (coming from the second upper argument of ${}_2\phi_0$). Something is wrong, apparently...

Comment: @Slaviks: Hmm, maybe I did not do the proper substitutions for Al-Salam-Carlitz II; let me check again, and I'll edit later...

Comment: I retract my comment - just realized the extra $q$-Pochhammer is coming from the definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Hope this does not goes against the rules here, but I wanted to post a more permanent  summary of the brainstorming that took place in the comments to the question.

- [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498/j-m) suggested writing

$$[k,n]_q = -\sum_{m=1}^n \prod_{\ell=0}^{m-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell-n+1}\right)$$

and

$$[k,n]_q = 1-{}_2\phi_1\left({{q^{-n},q}\atop{0}}; q, q^{k+1}\right)$$

- [anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/anon) noticed that point (4.) implies point (1.)

Comment: A summary is perfectly fine methinks. :) Did you already try browsing the database I gave you? (I'm also thinking you'll eventually need to read up on basic hypergeometric series anyway...)

Comment: No, not yet - it appears quite dense to me. I'm presently struggling to transform your basic hypergeometric function form into somethings that allows me to compute the $q \to 1^{-}$ via  [this property](http://dlmf.nist.gov/17.4.E2).

Comment: Well, I'll try searching+transforming myself, but maybe later (there are other things I need to look at for the time being). I was about to refer you to the DLMF for the time being, but I see you've gotten there already... :)

Comment: @J.M.: not without your help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58645/ :)

Comment: Another alternative expression, obtained by reversing summation/multiplication order, is $$\sum _{m=0}^n \prod _{\ell=m+1}^n \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-\ell+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

Not a full answer, but there's a recurrence
$$[k,1]_q = q^{k}-q^{k+1}$$
$$[k,n+1]_q = \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-n}\right) \left([k,n]_q -1\right)$$

One derivation is
$$[k,n+1]_q = -\sum_{m=1}^{n+1} \prod_{\ell=0}^{m-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell-n}\right)$$
$$ = -\left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-n}\right) \sum_{m=1}^{n+1} \prod_{\ell=1}^{m-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell-n}\right)$$
Subst. $\ell^\prime = \ell - 1, \; m^\prime = m-1$
$$ = -\left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-n}\right) \sum_{m^\prime=0}^{n} \prod_{\ell^\prime=0}^{m^\prime-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell^\prime-n+1}\right)$$
$$ = \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-n}\right) \left(-1-\sum_{m^\prime=1}^{n} \prod_{\ell^\prime=0}^{m^\prime-1} \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k+\ell^\prime-n+1}\right)\right)$$
$$ = \left(q^{k+1}-q^{k-n}\right) \left([k,n]_q -1\right) $$

Comment: An alternative base case is $[k, 0]_q = 0$

Answer (score 4):

An alternative form, conjectured by my colleague:

$$[k,n]_q =1+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(-1)^i \frac{q^{(n-k)i+i(i-1)/2}}{1-q^{k+1}} (q^{k+1}\; ;q^{-1})_i=
1 - \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}  q^{i(i+1)/2+n-k-1} \prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(q^{n-j}-q^{n-k-1}) $$

Checked for small $k$ and $n$, still need to prove. 
But this form explicitly proves that $[k,n]_q$ are polynomials for $k<n$. Also, the number of terms does not grow with $n$.

**EDIT:**
Exploring the new form a bit more leads to a striking "reversal" relation:

$$[k,n]_q=1-q^{n-k} \sum_{m=0}^k q^{m(n+1)} (q^{-k} \;; q)_m=1-q^{n-k} \left (1 - [n,k]_q \right) $$

**EDIT-2**
Another empirical observation: $\frac{[k,n]_q}{(1-q^n)} q^{-k+(n-1)n/2}$ is a polynomial as well.